# invalid 'type' (character of argument

Tags: r, character

This is my code:

```
TF.vec <- c(rep("TRUE",10),rep("FALSE",10),rep("TRUE",5)) 
sum(TF.vec)
```

It gives the following error:

> Error in sum(TF.vec) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

not sure what I am needing to do in order to fix the character problem to get actual sum to equal 15 when sum() is put in

Comment: You're just making a vector with the strings `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`, not actual logical values

Comment: I am not very familiar with r, what steps would I take to fix this?

Comment: You can look at the docs `?logical`. Lose the quotation marks and you'll have logical values instead of just text

Comment: TF.vec <- as.logical(c(rep("TRUE",10),rep("FALSE",10),rep("TRUE",5)))